# Matching patterns based on query result in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query which returns three columns Contact Id's, No of participations, Year of participation.

Based on this query result, I need to look for the pattern if anyone attended for certain (same number every year) number of times over the years.

For example, 2 times every year or 3 times every year for 2 years or more consecutively (and not different number of times in each year).

From the sample below, contacts I would be interested to be pulling are 1008637, 1009256, 1010306 & 1011263

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Please see image for sample data.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide format sample data and expect result?

Comment: Hi D-Shih, My expected result would be the Ids of 1008637, 1009256, 1010306 & 1011263. As they are same no of participation's per year and in consecutive years.

Answer (score 0):

You would need an aggregation twice. Once to get the number of participations and then to check the number condition for each year.

```
select id
from (select id,year,count(*) as num_participations
      from tbl
      group by id,year
     ) t 
group by id 
having count(*) = count(distinct case when num_participations = 2 then year end)
```

Comment: Hi Vamsi, I need to get the list of Id's with criteria where there are same number of transactions for minimum 2 years or more consecutively.